# Which data structure(s) to back a Final Fantasy ATB-style queue? (a delay queue)

Tags: data-structures, simulation, priority-queue

Situation: There are several entities in a simulated environment, which has an artificial notion of time called "ticks", which has no link to real time. Each entity takes it in turns to move, but some are faster than others. This is expressed by a delay, in ticks. So entity A might have a delay of 10, and B 25. In this case the turn order would go:

A A B A A

I'm wondering what data structure to use. At first I automatically thought "priority queue" but the delays are relative to "current time" which complicates matters. Also, there will be entities with larger delays and it's not unforseeable that the program will run through millions of ticks. It seems silly for an internal counter to be building higher and higher when the delays themselves stay relatively small and don't increase.

So how would you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store the entities in a Heap and group them by their time left to wait.  The group  of entities that are next to move would be at the top of the Heap. You only have to update these entities. When their time remaining to wait drops to 0, you remove them from the heap. Put the next group of entities in line at the top of the Heap while decrementing their time to wait by the amount of time that just passed before the previous move.

For example:

Your Heap has 3 nodes (A,B, and C), the top is node A with two entities both having 5 ticks remaining.  The childern have 10 and 12 ticks remaining respectively.

- At time t=5 you move all the entities that are bucketed in node A
- Remove A from the Heap
- B moves to the top of the Heap with 10-5 = 5 ticks   remaining then
- repeat.

Comment: If instead of ordering the heap by "time to wait" you order it by "time at which this entity will next take action" then you don't have to decrement the "time to wait" of each entity.

Comment: When counting up you may have to take into account rolling over once you exceed the limits of Int or Int64 (if your battle is long running).

Comment: I meant time until the next action, but time to wait was less typing.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right BeWarned, it doesn't have to update the ticks remaining on every single entity every time the time changes? If so I like it!

Comment: That's right you only have to update the top node on the heap per tick, you also have to account for when nodes where added. For overlap, just recalculate the heap.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the best approach with regards to time complexity. However, I'm not 100% on how to do this. Bear in mind I've never implemented a heap!

I get the basic idea is to group events that will occur at similar times, and that if there are say N events but only M groups, each time the timer is incremented we only need to decrement M things, not N, so we want as few groups as possible, but also don't want to end up with huge numbers, so a balance is needed... am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm accepting this as it's the only solution that doesn't require updating every entry when incrementing the time, although I don't really understand it enough to implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me by your description that the concept of "what's next?" is more important than "how long is it until the next action?". This being the case, sort your queue by "next-to-go" or lowest number of ticks remaining to highest. Inserts, of course, get entered in their appropriate order, and altered entries ("Speed up" spells) get removed trom the queue, altered, and then re-entered appropriately.

Then, you just pop the next job off the queue. Whatever number of ticks it had remaining must be the "time-elapsed". Makes a pass over the queue, decrementing the ticks remaining field of each entry by the amount of ticks you just discovered.

This has the advantage of keeping track of the concept of time remaining, but also of not having to fire events or execute any other code for ticks that go by when there is no action to take. You can afford this, since there is no relation to real time at all. There is only "what's next?", and "How long did it take to get there?".

Comment: You are correct, "what's next?" is the important notion. What time it is or how long until the next action are completely unneeded as long as the events process in the right order.

I'm not sure about decrementing everything in the queue... there might be quite a few, and I want it to be fast. It's probably what I'll go with if I don't find a better way, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1: Polling**

I would probably build a controller that can discover the delay for all the different entities and maintain a ticks-remaining for each entity.  The controller would cycle through ticks and on each tick it would reduce the ticks-remaining for all entities in the game.

Once an entities ticks-remaining value reaches zero you know it's their turn, either controlled by the heartbeat method that handles the ticks or a method that you call.

**Option #2 Events**

Think like the UI paradigm, the interface doesn't constantly poll the button to see when it is clicked.  Rather it let's the button notify the UI when it has been clicked via events.  Have your Entities (or an EntityBattleContext) fire an event when it is ready. You will have to handle you game time in some manner, since it isn't based off real world time at all you may need to have all the Entities listen for a GameTick event and when they receiver that event update their interal TicksRemaining variable.

Before following the event driven route make sure the polling route won't work. Remember the cardinal rule *always optimize later* because more often then not you don't need the optimization.

Comment: Seems viable, but possibly a little slow if there are a lot of entities?

Comment: Well, I suppose if you have a lot of entities you don't want to use a polling system.  Rather set up an event that each entity fires when it is ready.  That way your controller just has to receiver events process the entities that way.

Comment: Both of these methods are pretty ineffecient as you step through each tick. Usually in simulations of this nature you skip the large gaps in time where nothing happens rather than increment through them.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your entities are observing or watching the simulation time, they could each implement an interface which makes them track the `ticks left` and provides a method to get how many ticks are left for a particular entity. At each tick, the entity reduces its `ticks left` by 1.

You could then keep a sorted set queue (set because each entity will be in the queue only once) of these entities, sorted based on `get ticks left`, so that the 0th entity is the one to move next, and the Nth entity is the "slowest".

When the entity's `get ticks left` method is 0, it is removed from the sorted set, the `ticks left` timer is reset, and it is re-inserted into the sorted set.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how Java's [DelayQueue](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=ru#ybd8S83PG4Q/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.java&q=delayqueue.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) is implemented.

Comment: Global notion of time, each element knows when it is due, and exposes a relative time on getDelay and compareTo. This still suffers from the overflow problem.